# command prompt when i try install any dependence

Tags: node.js

when I try to install any dependence in command prompt get this error message and tried to google but nothing any one to help me please

[image]

please I need help someone to help me

Answer (score 0):

try installing locally. and add this path to your system variable: C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the node.

You have two ways to install Node.js on your computer.

**Option 1 – Setup by running the .msi installation file**

- Its a typical Windows installation and automated. No need to add
  entries in environment varaiable

**Option 2 – Setup by extracting .zip file**

- This method does not require admin access and can be used to install
  on nodejs on a system on which you dont have admin access such as you
  official laptop or desktop.
- Removing nodejs is as simple as deleting    the folder. You will have
  to add entries in environment variable if    you want to execute node
  command from any location in windows command    prompt. https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot.your access is denied.Would suggest starting the terminal as an administrator before running the command.